# Property 'View; not found on object of type "x"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm currently developing an Radio application for the iPhone on Xcode SDK iOS 5, and I'm currently using some elements from the StichedStreamPlayer that apple has made available. The problem i am having problem with is the `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` part

Here is my Code:

```
appDelegate.m

#import "iGamerFMAppDelegate.h"

@class iGamerFMStreamingViewController;

@implementation iGamerFMAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

@synthesize iGamerFMViewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

{

    //Adds the streaming view controller once finished loading

    [window addSubview:iGamerFMViewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

-(void)dealloc

{

    [window release];

    [iGamerFMViewController release];

    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

I get an error  - Property 'View' not found on object of type "iGamerFMViewController"
I have tried everything from rewriting it to copy and paste from another project and it still doesnt work. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you have a @class declaration in the .m file? You need to need to import the .h-file. How are you initializing iGamerFMStreamingViewController?

Comment: iGamerFMViewController is the class or the object?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the right class selected for your view controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the code for `iGamerFMViewController`?

I am assuming that `iGamerFMViewController` should subclass `UIViewController` so it should look like this

```
@interface iGamerFMViewController : UIViewController
```

or if it does not does `iGamerFMViewController` have a property called `view`

Side note - Class' normally start with a capital letter it makes it clearer that it is a class and not a variable or method.

Also you normally would do your `#import "iGamerFMStreamingViewController.h"` in the .m file otherwise the compiler has to read the whole class each as opposed to just it's header.