# too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 3

Tags: ios, json, compiler-errors, arguments

Please help me to find the error, my code is

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx_webservice/login.php?user=%@&pass=%@&format=json",Username,Password];
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like this. First make a proper string of your URL and then encode it and then finally make it a `NSURL`. Make sure your passing the correct and right set of parameters.

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/xx_webservice/login.php?user=%@&pass=%@&format=json",Username,Password];
NSString *encdLink = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:encdLink];
```

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Click the right mark.

Comment: i am trying to add image in MKMap but it shows error kindly guide me the error is "Property 'image' not found on object of type 'Annotation *'" and my code is "myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza_slice_32.png"]" i am blocked for ask questions please help me Thank you

Comment: You need to post or share me some code so that I can make out what exactly is this.

Comment: My code is,myAnnotation.title=addressOutlet;
            myAnnotation.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", City, State];
             myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"condominium-map-icon.png"];

Comment: Please help me I am blocked for asking questions

Comment: Seeing your code, I am still unable to get a clear idea about problem. But look out for these things. Make sure you have the right class selected for your view controller. And also make sure that the property name is correct. Also refer these links, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369543/unable-to-load-a-uiimage-in-a-uiimageview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921294/property-images-not-found-on-object-of-type-uiviewcontroller   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886438/property-view-not-found-on-object-of-type-x